# Where do I ask about adding a tag?

Tags: discussion, support

I thought it would be nice to have [transformation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) added, and possibly linked to [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) because sometimes I know a word and want to get it into another form.  I don't know the word in the other form. I think that's commonly known as *transforming a word*.

Comment: Do you mean like turning a noun into an adjective? I think dictionaries give you those forms, in which case these questions would all be general reference.

Comment: The answer to your title appears to be "Here"; the answer to the body of the question seems to be mildly negative. The general answer is that anyone with 300 rep can add a tag, at the risk of having it removed by the community. Could you clarify please?

Comment: TimLymington: That's enough info, though the 'here' you put in doesn't link to anything.  If you were going to add an important link, I'll up it.  Also wondering about merge votes.  Thank you.

Comment: @TimLymington is saying that the answer to "Where do I ask about adding a tag?" is here on this very site; as your reputation is higher than 300, you could add the tag yourself, even though the tag would probably be removed. TimLymington is probably wondering if you are asking somebody else to add the tag for you, or you are asking if the tag would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to "Where do I ask about adding a tag?" is here on this very site; that is the answer whatever you mean where to ask somebody else to add the tag for you (which could also be done commenting the question that would need a tag that doesn't exist), or where to ask about the appropriateness of a new tag you think to use for a question.

I don't think [transformation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformation) is going to add anything useful to questions. There are already tags such as [nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns), [pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns), [adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjectives), and other similar tags. You can use those tags.

I don't see much questions about transformation of words, to start using that tag. As simchona says, I fear that those questions would be closed as general reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a comprehensive reference of transformations in publication, either.  Sadly, I suppose there's just no place for questions like these.

Comment: @wolfpack maybe because there are dictionaries for that.

Comment: @simchona No, there aren't.  That's why I said there aren't any in publication.

Comment: @wolfpack normal dictionaries list the other grammar forms of given words

Comment: @simchona No sense arguing.  Good comment.  *Smile*